# Pytables 2.3.1 with Python 2.5 on Windows: Error - could not find a local hdf5 installation

Tags: python, pytables

I'm trying to install PyTables 2.3.1 on Windows XP with Python 2.5. I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 
headers and library can be found by setting the HDF5_DIR 
environment variable or by using the --hdf5 command-line option.
```

I'm a bit confused by the installation of the HDF5 library. I downloaded the Windows binary called `HDF5188-win32-shared.zip` from the [HDF5 site](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html) and ran the .exe file in the zip archive. I now have what looks like an installation of the HDF5 library in this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.8
```

I've tried creating an environment variable called HDF5_DIR pointing to this folder, but still no joy. I'm obviously not installing the right bit of the HDF5 library, but I don't know what I should be doing instead.

Does anyone have any suggestions, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [docs](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/installation.html#binaryinstallationdescr) you can try:
Put the DLL libraries (hdf5dll.dll and, optionally, lzo1.dll and bzip2.dll)

> in a directory listed in your PATH environment variable

. The setup.py installation program will print out a warning to that effect if the libraries can not be found.

locate

> hdf5dll.dll

and make sure dir containig it is in the PATH var or you can try --hdf5=path/to/ command

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'd downloaded the wrong version of the HDF5 library. The win32-shared.zip one, mentioned above, doesn't seem to have hdf5dll.dll. I downloaded a different version and everything's working now. Cheers!

Comment: @JamesS: I am having the same problem. Could you please add a link to the different version that contains hdf5dll.dll? Thanks