# 'HDF5dll.dll not found' error on running Python Pytables

Tags: c#, python, dll, pytables

I can see that my question was asked previously (back in 2012) and an answer was provided. Here's the original question:

[Pytables 2.3.1 with Python 2.5 on Windows: Error - could not find a local hdf5 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042915/pytables-2-3-1-with-python-2-5-on-windows-error-could-not-find-a-local-hdf5-i)

The suggestion was made at that time to simply add a "--HDF5\path to\" command to the Pytables install statement. Adding this command doesn't work if you don't have a specific DLL file -- HDF5DLL.DLL -- in your HDF5 folder. As noted in the 2012 OQ, several queries as to possible workarounds to this second level error went unanswered.

As noted in 2012, this DLL does *not* come as part of the Windows 32-bit, HDF5-1.8.15 gzipped download (the most recent release).

Note that I'm running Python 2.7 on an old Windows XP workstation, but that isn't relevant to answering this question.

There are lots of websites out there which offer a download of this DLL file. In the absence of reliable guidance, it would be a bit like Russian Roulette to randomly select one for downloading.

Who else has dealt with this specific challenge? What are the workarounds?

Thank you.

Comment: Downloading Sci-Lab, the free numerical integration tool, provided the needed DLLs.